# I try to give value for a 2 dimensional matrix using for loop in R, however it gives me unexpected NA values

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I want to calculate the moving sum with varying window sizes of 1:15.

```
a <- matrix(0,257,15)
b <- c(1:257)
for(j in 1:15) {
  for(i in j:257) {
    a[i,j] <- sum(b[i-j+1:i])
  }
}
```

However, the above code gives cases me confusion, as it yields `NA` after the 129th row in every column. What could be reason for such behaviour?

Comment: You should use parentheses inside sum: `sum(b[(i-j+1):i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parentheses `(...):i` into indexing of `b[(i-j+1):i]` in order to properly have a range between `i-j+1` and `i`. The full code then reads as

```
a <- matrix(0,257,15)
b <- c(1:257)
for (j in 1:15) {
  for (i in j:257) {
    a[i,j] <- sum(b[(i-j+1):i])
  }
}
```

As an example on the importance of the parentheses, you may compare the calculating order of the following three cases:

```
> (1+1):2
[1] 2
> 1+1:2
[1] 2 3
> 1+(1:2)
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm replicating exactly same results. There must be some kind of bug (or feature unknown to me) in R engine. The expressions are correct (added "bCoordinetes" to check those). The results get fixed when closing the row expression in brackets:

```
a <- matrix(0,257,15)
bCoordinates <- matrix(0,257,15) #added just for validation - not needed for results
b <- c(1:257) 
for(j in 1:15) {
  for(i in j:257) {
    a[i,j] <- sum(b[(i-j+1):i]) #closing column calc to brackets fixes the issue
    bCoordinates[i,j] <- i-j+1  #added just for validation - not needed for results
  }
}
```